# Добавление товара в корзину в интернет магазине

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Появился такой вопрос:
В одном интернет магазине я делал скрипт добавления товара в корзину вот так:
делал функцию которая будет срабатывать при нажатии на кнопку, которая будет отправлять данные на сервер.
Все это дело выглядит вот так

```
<a href="javascript:addtocart('111');" class="product_buy_btn"></a>

function addtocart(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addtocart.php",
        data: "id="+id,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $(".sc_block").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

в класс sc_block выводиться инфа после обработки.

А теперь сама задача.
Как обойтись без функции и сделать чтобы при нажатии на объект `<a>` с классом `product_buy_btn`, выбиралось дополнительное поле `data-id="111"` и отправлялось на сервер. Хочу получить вот такую кнопку `<a href="" data-id="111" class="product_buy_btn">Кнопка</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.product_buy_btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // дальше ваш ajax-запрос
});
```